# Python: How can I initialize class of NamedTuple

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-decorators, namedtuple

I want to create a class, and I don’t want its attributes to be modified after new, so I choose `NamedTuple`,

But I hope that It can do something immediately after initialize,

So I hope to I can override the `__init__` method,

but if I do this, I will encounter **AttributeError: Cannot overwrite NamedTuple attribute `__init__`.**

Is there any elegant code that can do it?

My actual case is to initialize the style of `ttk`, as follows.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from typing import NamedTuple


class TTKStyle(NamedTuple):
    LF_NORMAL = f'Normal.TLabelframe'

    def init_style(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure(self.LF_NORMAL, background='#FFFF00')
        style.configure(f'{self.LF_NORMAL}.Label', foreground='red', background='blue', font=('courier', 15, 'bold'))


root = tk.Tk()
ttk_style = TTKStyle()
ttk_style.init_style()  # <-- I don't want to write this line.
lf_exif = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text='EXIF Tag', style=ttk_style.LF_NORMAL)
lf_exif.pack()
tk.Label(lf_exif, text='ExifVersion').pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not just use a normal class? If you don't want the attributes to be modified, just don't write code that modifies them.

Comment: Exactly: use a plain class, with a factory method if needed

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley, Yes, I can let me do not modify it because I am the author,
Anyone who is not the author may since it does not understand my purpose and change it, even myself may modify in uncareful.
that is why I need read-only (private) attributes. (The example is too simple, resulting you think that use the normal class is not a big deal.)
Despite the normal class can constraint too, but need to write more code...
And I have updated my answer. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Ehm... mine is a comment. I haven't downvoted the question

Comment: @Pynchia I am sorry for I mistake you, and I have deleted the kind of emotional comments. Have a good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Decorator

You can use the decorator to help you.

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Type


def init_namedtuple(init_func_name):
    def wrap(class_obj: Type[NamedTuple]):
        def new_instance(*args, **kwargs):
            instance_obj = class_obj(*args, **kwargs)
            init_func = getattr(instance_obj, init_func_name)
            if init_func:
                init_func()
            return instance_obj

        return new_instance

    return wrap


@init_namedtuple('init_style')
class TTKStyle(NamedTuple):
    ...
```

---

## __slots__

or you can use normal class and add `__slots__` and put your init function on `__init__` directly (`see class Person3`), for example:

```
from typing import NamedTuple
class Person(NamedTuple):
    NAME: str
    SCIENTIFIC_NAME = 'Homo sapiens'

class Person2:
    __slots__ = ()
    NAME: str
    SCIENTIFIC_NAME = 'Homo sapiens'


class Person3:
    __slots__ = ()

    NAME: str
    SCIENTIFIC_NAME = 'Homo sapiens'

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.__class__.NAME = name
        ...
class Person4:
    __slots__ = ('_name', '_scientific_name')

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self._name = name  # Technically, the way is not really read-only, but a conventional is so. 
        self._scientific_name = 'Homo sapiens'

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def scientific_name(self):
        return self._scientific_name
```

```py
for person in (Person('Carson'), Person('Carson2')):
    print(person.NAME)  # output: Carson, Carson2


for person in (Person4('Carson3'), Person4('Carson4')):
    print(person.name)  # output: Carson3, Carson4

if "it's ok but weird":
    unknown_person = Person2()
    unknown_person.__class__.NAME = '???'
    print(unknown_person.NAME)

for person in [Person3('Marry'), Person3('Marry2')]:
    # BE CAREFUL! IF YOU USE THE CLASS ATTRIBUTE, THEN ALL THE INSTANCES IS SHARED THIS VARIABLE.
    print(person.NAME)  # both output is: Marry2
```

The class of all the above attributes is read-only (for 2 and 3, you can change it from the class but not change from instance) and not accept other new attributes.